# W: Webpacker requires Node.js ">=10.17.0" and you are using v6.17.1

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, webpack, deployment, ruby-on-rails-6

I try to deploy the rails 6 App on platform.sh,
I have this error when deploying my project in Rails 6 with Webpacker 5.2.1.

I have done days of research on google, without success.
I have NVM installed locally, node and npm, I will say that everything is fine locally, the webpacker is compiled correctly, but not on the remote machine.
and this error makes the deployment fail.

```
    W: Webpacker requires Node.js ">=10.17.0" and you are using v6.17.1
    W: Please upgrade Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
    W: Exiting!
  
  E: Error building project: Step failed with status code 1.

E: Error: Unable to build application, aborting.
```

when I want to compile the assets with this line on Build hook.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

can you help me
I'll share my config

**.platform.app.yaml**

```
    # The name of this app. Must be unique within a project.
name: app
type: 'ruby:2.7'
mounts:
    log:
      source: local
      source_path: log
    tmp:
      source: local
      source_path: tmp
relationships:
    postgresdatabase: 'dbpostgres:postgresql'
# The size of the persistent disk of the application (in MB).
disk: 1024
hooks:
    build: |
      bundle install --without development test
      RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails webpacker:install               
    deploy: |
      RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate 
web:
  upstream: 
    socket_family: "unix"
  commands: 
    start: "unicorn -l $SOCKET -E production config.ru"
  locations: 
    '/': 
      root: "public"
      passthru: true
      expires: 1h
      allow: true
```

**services.yaml**

```
dbpostgres:
# The type of your service (postgresql), which uses the format
# 'type:version'. Be sure to consult the PostgreSQL documentation
# (https://docs.platform.sh/configuration/services/postgresql.html#supported-versions)
# when choosing a version. If you specify a version number which is not available,
# the CLI will return an error.
type: postgresql:13
 # The disk attribute is the size of the persistent disk (in MB) allocated to the service.
disk: 9216
configuration:
  extensions:
    - plpgsql
    - pgcrypto
    - uuid-ossp
```

***routes.yaml***

```
    # Each route describes how an incoming URL is going to be processed by Platform.sh.
"https://www.{default}/":
    type: upstream
    upstream: "app:http"

"https://{default}/":
    type: redirect
    to: "https://www.{default}/"
```

Comment: Did you check https://docs.platform.sh/languages/nodejs/nvm.html ?
Seems like you need to specify both nvm and node versions

Comment: It helped me to compile to make of deployment. except that I have another error message donations I do not understand well, but it is also related to webpacker. seem log out:     `I, [2021-04-29T18:39:54.344608 #289]  INFO -- : [myqjuxs5ehsp6pdpbfdibpkc] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 44ms (ActiveRecord: 7.5ms | Allocations: 3372)
F, [2021-04-29T18:39:54.351297 #289] FATAL -- : [myqjuxs5ehsp6pdpbfdibpkc]
[myqjuxs5ehsp6pdpbfdibpkc] ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.css in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
`

Comment: end comment: `1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:`

Comment: Are you importing `application.css` on any of your Webpack javascript files? If you're not, then try adding `extract_css: false` to `config/webpacker.yml`

Comment: Or maybe you don't want to compile your css with Webpacker, then you should remove `= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application'` from your application layout.
If you are importing application.css, post the generated `app/public/packs/manifest.json`